# How to restrict a Google Service Account to a single bucket in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-iam

Is it possible to do this?

The analogous feature in AWS using IAM does support restricting access to a single bucket, but from looking https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts it doesnt look like it is possible in GCP.

Answer (score 11):

To restrict access for a service account to a specific bucket using IAM permissions you can use gsutil:

```
    gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com:objectViewer gs://${BUCKET}
```

And repeat for each role you want to grant (eg `objectAdmin`).

The docs are here [Using Cloud IAM with buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions). If you need finer control on specific objects, you have to use ACLs.

Answer (score 3):

The Identity and Access Management (IAM) and service account permissions are the recommended methods for controlling access to your resources for a general scope; However, you should rather use [Access Control Lists](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) in case you want to customize the access scope to individual buckets and it's objects.

I recommend you to take a look on the [Creating and Managing Access Control Lists](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists) guide that contains detail information about the usage of ACLs as well as the step-by-step instructions to set [ACL permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#set-an-acl) to an existing bucket.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. Create a new service account.
2. Edit permissions for bucket "XYZ". Add `Legacy Bucket Reader` role for the service account from point #1.

And that's all.

---

The biggest problem I had is that I assumed that Legacy roles are not supposed to be used...

See: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#legacy-roles

Comment: Does this still works? I used it before, but now I'm unable to add a role to a service account at the permissions bucket screen, "Role cannot be edited as it is inherited from another resource"

Comment: Same here - and it is not logic to me. Why should a service account have access to all buckets? Any update on this?

Comment: @Stiefel I just got it to work - the key for me is when you create the service account to skip step 2, i.e. don't grant it general permissions for the project. Then you can add it as a member to the bucket and add the role then.